# Exception on Jersey validation

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to use Bean Validation with Jersey 2.0. When the submitted input is invalid I'm receiving a strange exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [API] in context with path [/API] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/message/MessageUtils] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.MessageUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationErrorMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(ValidationErrorMessageBodyWriter.java:162)
(...)
```

My resource method looks like this:

```
@PUT
public Response createSchedule(@BeanParam @Valid Schedule schedule) {
(...)
```

In the bean class I use only one annotation constraint

```
@NotEmpty
protected String name;
```

...and the `ResourceConfig`:

```
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application() {
            super();

            packages( "com.test.api.resource" );

            register(MustacheMvcFeature.class);
            register(ResponseBodyWriter.class);

            property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
            property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
    }

}
```

I would like to display a JSON formatted error message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an incorrect version on `jersey-bean-validation`. The library version was higher than my Jersey.